# Which subject deals with questions like "Distance from hyperplane to a point"

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What subject covers topics like the following for N dimensions?

1. Given equation of plane like Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, the normal vector N is given by $[A,B,C]^{T}$?
2. What is the distance between a point and a hyperplane?

I had studied these results for 2-dimensional co-ordinate geometry in high school, but I am not sure which subject covers topics/results for questions like above?

I've read Gilbert strang's linear algebra book > 3 years ago, but I don't remember that book covering such geometric results for a N-dimensional space.

Comment: It's analytic geometric. Requires linear algebra.

Comment: See _inner-product vector spaces_ in a textbook on **linear algebra**.

Comment: It's *linear algebra*. I learnt my linear algebra from this text:
http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~rvl/linalg/2013/LinAlg1_2013_links.pdf
Your questions are answered on pages 34-36.